# Selecting a WHOLE string from file [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

The problem I have here is that, while the program has no direct syntax errors, if I only put in part of the password (e.g. password= password but my input could just be "pass").

So, **what I am asking here**, is how to select a *whole* string in a file.

Is it my use of `split` that has made it possible that the program allows a partial copy of the correct password through?

Or what is it?

```
with open("users.txt") as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f):
        l.split(":")
        l.strip()
        if username in l:
            print("you exist...") 
            password= input("please input your password ")
            while password not in l:
                password=input("Enter your password")
```

The file looks like this:

```
me:password123 
user1:12345678 
user2:12345678
```

Where the left column is the username and the right is the password

Comment: What does your file look like? (Edit your question to include it)

Comment: me:password123
user1:12345678
user2:12345678

Comment: Why are you throwing away the list returned by `l.split(":")`?

Comment: How so? I mean, the strip function doesn't appear to alter it when I removed it

Comment: `string.split` and `string.strip` isn't *inplace* operations.

Comment: `l.split(":")` splits the string `l` into substrings, putting the substrings into a list, which it returns. But you aren't saving the return value. On a similar note, `l.strip()` creates a new string containing the chars from `l` with the leading & trailing whitespace removed. But you aren't saving that new string. In Python, the string methods don't modify the original string because Python strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dictionary to store the password data, with the username as the key, and the password as the value. Of course, in a real program you should **not** save passwords as plain text!

```
import sys

passwords = {}

with open("users.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, word = line.split(":")
        passwords[name.strip()] = word.strip()

username = input("Please enter your username: ")
if username in passwords:
    print("you exist...")
    real_password = passwords[username]
    password = ''
    while password != real_password:
        password = input("Please enter your password: ")
else:
    print("you don't exist")
    sys.exit()

print('Welcome,', username)
```

We know that there are exactly two items on each line of "users.txt", so we can use `line.split(":")` to build a list containing those two strings. And we can assign those strings to separate variables by using tuple assignment:

```
name, word = line.split(":")
```

However, there might be unwanted whitespaces on either side of those strings, so we need to call the `.strip()` method on each of them before we put them into the `passwords` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

`string.strip` and `string.split` both isn't inplace operations, you will need to catch the returned argument like this:

```
username = input("Username: ")

with open("users.txt") as f:
    for l in f:
        l = l.strip() # save the returned value
        uname, upass = l.split(":") # split at : and assign it to variables           
        if username == uname: # check if the usernames match
            print("you exist...") 
            password= input("please input your password ")

            while password != upass: # check to see if the password match
                password=input("Enter your password") 

            break # break out of the for loop
```

There are still many improvements can be made, and I'll leave those to you to make(that was intentional). Though there are also some mistakes to fix, for example: If there's a colon ":" in the username or password it will also get split.

Answer (score 0):

```
username = str(input("Username: "))
password = str(input("Password: "))

f = open("test.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
for index in range(len(f) - 1):
    if f[index] == username and f[index + 1] == password:
        print("Login made")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.